# Visualizing linux GPT partition (EFI) from Windows Host

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, virtualbox, virtualization, grub-efi

I created a rescue grub.iso using the following script. This code worked for me when I using Windows 7, Ubuntu 12, MBR:

```
#!/bin/sh
set -e

wk_dir=$(mktemp -d "${TMPDIR:-/tmp}/tmp.XXXXXXXXXX")
mkdir -p ${wk_dir}/boot/grub

grub-mkconfig -o /boot/grub/grub.cfg

# copy your /boot/grub/grub.cfg file to the work dir
cp -v /boot/grub/grub.cfg ${wk_dir}/boot/grub/grub.cfg

# run grub-mkrescue should create new image grub.iso in the current dir
grub-mkrescue --modules="ext2 lvm" -o /home/john/Dropbox/grub.iso ${wk_dir}

rm -rf ${wk_dir}
```

Now that I am using Windows 8, Ubuntu 14, GPT, using the `grub.iso` created from the above script and made sure to check `Enabled EFI` on Settings -> System. I would fall back to grub prompt, so I typed:

```
set root=(hd0,gpt5) 
set prefix=(hd0,gpt5)/boot/grub 
insmod normal 
normal
```

and I was able to get to grub, only to encounter the following error:
[image]

I searched through and through the web to find someone visualizing a partition from Windows 8, but I couldn't find any. I think there is a limitation on 64-bit system for UEFI from virtualbox, but I wasn't sure. If anybody know how to do this, please set me to the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

Reinstalled Virtualbox and Disabled Fastboot in Windows 8.1 and it worked.